# Reclassifying raster with 33 bands in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, reclassify, multi-band

I have a file geodatabase raster dataset with 33 bands. Each band is comprised of pixels with values 1-31. This represents 33 years of landuse cover data (with 31 different landuse classes). I'm trying to move from this format to a single TIFF file that has 1 band comprised of pixels with the value 1-33, corresponding to the year that the pixel switched from forest to non-forest. Its a huge file (100GB), so I need to reduce the file size before I can do any analysis.

My plan is to reclassify each band/year into 0 (forest) and 1 (non-forest), then sum all the bands (using the raster calculator, I think?). However, the reclassify tool is only reclassifying a single band.

How do I do this for all the bands.

Comment: If result of sum will say 2, what that means for you?

Comment: @FelixIP I could use it to calculate the year of deforestation. The dataset goes through 2017, so for each pixel, it would be 2017- (final raster value) = year deforested

Answer (score 1):

Big task it is. So set environment settings - cell size, snap raster and extent, to ones of that raster.
Run script below from ArcMap or ArcCatalog:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
## change next 2 lines
ForestCode=184
multiBand="F:/AERIALS/Rectified/image0051.tif"
## output raster name
outRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

nBands=int(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(multiBand, "BANDCOUNT")[0])
outList=[]
for i in range(nBands):
    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(multiBand,"AFTER","","",i+1)
    after=arcpy.Raster("AFTER")
    if i>0:
        deforest=Con((before==ForestCode) & (after != ForestCode),i)
        outList.append(deforest)
    before=after*1
    arcpy.AddMessage("Band %i processed" %i) 
arcpy.AddMessage("Computing last year of deforestation ...")
deforest=CellStatistics(outList, "MAXIMUM", "DATA")
deforest.save(outRaster)
```

I strongly suggest to test it on a tiny subset first, i.e. clip bit of that monster in the area where deforestation certainly happened.

Update:

Replace 184 by value that represents forest in your raster.
Script compares consecutive pair of bands - before and after - to find when last deforestation happened.

If you think that 'before' is not defined during first reference, have a better look at the code.

Comment: thanks for answering. I'm going to be honest, I have absolutely no idea what this code is doing. I have a few specific questions, but would you mind explaining what's happening here in general? I also specifically don't understand the line ForestCode= 184. What is this line doing/ what is 184? also, can you explain what's happening with before==ForestCode?-- "before" isn't defined prior to this line.